# Changing three standalone mongodb servers to a replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I have three standalone MongoDB database servers each with different data, but the same dbs and collection names. I've converted them into a replicated set and now whenever I read from the primary server I only get data that was on that specific server from before the replicated set initialization. Is this the expected behavior? Do I have to wait for all servers to get into sync before being able to read the data that was in all three databases?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a replica set, each of the secondaries syncs data off of the primary to ensure that all the nodes have the same copy of the data - there is no "merge" of the data.  The two nodes that did became secondaries would have completely wiped and resynced their data.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication-internals/#syncing.

If the data from the two secondaries was not backed up anywhere, you may have lost it.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation that states that the data is wiped out, are you sure? I'm going to try and remove it and see if the data is still there.

Comment: Ok, so I set rs.slaveOk() on the secondary, and you're right, the data is gone. It's not a big deal since this is just the very beginning of data collection and it wasn't really valuable anyway. Thanks

Comment: No worries.  In the future, you should make sure that when you start up a replica set the data directories are clean.  You can then do a mongodump and mongoimport on existing data from other db's to bring it into the replica set.